Index terrraform resources
In our Terraform infrastructure, we generate resources dynamically: a local script is executed and returns a list: something like that:
module "subdomains" {
  source = "../modules/subdomains"
}

module "cluster" {
  for_each = module.subdomains.subdomains

  source = "..."

  module_name  = each.value.subdomain_name
}

The strings in this list contains URL path, like:
"/subdomains/random.mydomain.com",
"/subdomains/another.mydomain.com",

How can I address these resources in command line, e.g.: terraform destroy --target=...
I have tried without success:
terraform destroy module.cluster["/subdomains/random.mydomain.com"]
╷
│ Error: Index value required
│ 
│   on  line 1:
│   (source code not available)
│ 
│ Index brackets must contain either a literal number or a literal string.

Can anybody help me?
Thank you

Please edit your post and include more details about the module. The generated terraform plan would be useful as well.

You need to use quotes, e.g.:
$ terraform destroy -target='module.cluster["/subdomains/random.mydomain.com"]'

